# What is "= delete"?

Tags: c++, c++11, deleted-functions

What do these two strange lines of code mean?

```
thread_guard(thread_guard const&) = delete;

thread_guard& operator=(thread_guard const&) = delete;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `=delete` is a new feature of C++0x. It means the compiler should immediately stop compiling and complain "this function is deleted" once the user use such function (See also: [*defaulted and deleted functions -- control of defaults*](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#default) of the C++0x FAQ by Bjarne Stroustrup).

The `thread_guard(thread_guard const&)` is a copy constructor, and `thread_guard& operator=(thread_guard const&)` is an assignment constructor. These two lines together therefore disables copying of the `thread_guard` instances.

Comment: Almost. The "use" of a deleted function in an unevaluated context (for example, as expression to `decltype`) can qualify as a template argument deduction failure. This makes a compiler just ignore a template. It doesn't make the compiler stop compiling.

Answer (score 10):

It is the new C++0x syntax for disabling the certain functions of the class. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Explicitly-defaulted_and_deleted_special_member_functions)  for an example. Here you are telling that class `thread_guard` is neither copyable nor assignable.